# Basic databinding example with PowerShell and ShowUI - can't make it work at all

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding, showui

I'm using [ShowUI](https://github.com/ShowUI/ShowUI) to explore PowerShell GUIs, it's based on WPF behind the scenes, and I'm trying to get databinding to work. Ideally I'd like a hashtable of my data and textboxes bound to the properties, so that typing in the textboxes updates the hashtable and updating the hashtable updates the textboxes. Or something approximating that.

I don't know my way around WPF databinding, I'm trying things like this:

```
ipmo  showui

StackPanel {
    label -name "a" -Content { binding -ElementBinding b -path Text }
    Textbox -name "b"
} -Show
```

and what I get is a UI showing up, but typing doesn't change anything. I've tried quite a few trial-and-error variations on this - setting the binding on the TextBox instead using `Textbox -Text { binding... }`, or binding on both, using syntax like `binding -Source a` instead of ElementBinding, using `binding -Source $a` with the control's variable name, using -DataContexts on the textbox or on the parent stackpanel, trying with and without default values in various places for the commands. I've tried using a `button` with an event handler that updates a hashtable and trying to bind the hashtable, or with a PSCustomObject; binding a textbox to a slider value - a lot of trial and error, but no result.

There is an example of databinding in ShowUI [here](https://github.com/ShowUI/ShowUI/blob/dev/Examples/BootsBindingAndCurrentItem.ps1) which pulls command help into a list and steps through it, that appears to work fine. And the [first example here](https://github.com/ShowUI/ShowUI/blob/dev/Examples/BootsBindingAndTemplates.ps1) also works fine - as long as you have pictures in the folder. These make me think ShowUI can handle databinding - and without scaffolding or initialization code.

Following [this C# tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/simple-data-binding-in-wpf/) and trying to port it almost literally to ShowUI, I get this:

```
ipmo showui

$s = [pscustomobject]@{fname="Mahak"; lname="Garg";}

Grid -Name "StuInfo" -rows 3 {
    TextBox -Text { Binding fname } -row 0
    Textbox -Text { Binding lname } -row 1
    Button -name "button1" -Content "Next" -row 2 -On_Click { 
        $s2 = [pscustomobject]@{fname="Jupi"; lname="Gupta";}
        $stuinfo.DataContext = $s2
        Write-Host "."
    }
} -On_Loaded {
    $stuinfo.DataContext = $s
} -show
```

And the UI appears, and the data does not. Clicking the button writes a `.` to the console, but does not update the textboxes.

I'm using PowerShell 4 so I can't directly use classes, and the latest ShowUI 1.5 (I think) dev branch from Github. [Edit: this was at least part of my problem, actually using an old version on one computer and a new version on another]

What am I missing or misunderstanding?

Comment: Have you tried replace `$stuinfo` with `$This`? Ex. `$This.DataContext = $s`

Comment: @boeprox I had not tried it, but I have now - and can't see any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used ShowUI before (didn't know it existed until I saw this question). So, I downloaded it and tried your script above. I got the same results as you did. I found that the $s variable in the On_Loaded method was null. Changing the two instances of $s to $global:s made it work:

```
ipmo showui

$global:s = [pscustomobject]@{fname="Mahak"; lname="Garg";}

Grid -Name "StuInfo" -rows 3 {
    TextBox -Text { Binding fname } -row 0
    Textbox -Text { Binding lname } -row 1
    Button -name "button1" -Content "Next" -row 2 -On_Click { 
        $s2 = [pscustomobject]@{fname="Jupi"; lname="Gupta";}
        $stuinfo.DataContext = $s2
        Write-Host "."
    }
} -On_Loaded {
    $stuinfo.DataContext = $global:s
} -show
```

The first script you had, I couldn't get binding to an element working. I tried using a DataContext to link them that way and it worked... sort of. It seems like whatever binds to the property first is the only item that can update it. So, if the textbox is first then it worked but if the label was first it didn't work.

Works:

```
ipmo  showui

$dc = [pscustomobject]@{ myText="my text" }

StackPanel {
    Textbox -Text {Binding -Path myText -UpdateSourceTrigger PropertyChanged}
    Label -Content {Binding -Path myText}
} -Show -DataContext @($dc)

$dc
```

Didn't work:

```
ipmo  showui

$dc = [pscustomobject]@{ myText="my text" }

StackPanel {
    Label -Content {Binding -Path myText}
    Textbox -Text {Binding -Path myText -UpdateSourceTrigger PropertyChanged}
} -Show -DataContext @($dc)

$dc
```

I hope this helps you some... it seems like ShowUI would be a nice tool but IDK, seems buggy.

Comment: Good find about the variable scoping. I tried it and it didn't work for me - went looking around and realised I had only updated ShowUI on my other computer, not this one - still running a version from 2013. *oops*. Yes, with updated ShowUI, your working examples do work - thank you very much. I'll leave the question open for a bit, for a chance of other answers, but this is a good one.